# Create two graph view for one model openerp

Tags: odoo

I want Create two graph view for one model openerp, I like to define Two menu for each one display a graph view,
exemple one content graph by country the ather by gender

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. The way the site works is: 1/ You try to find a good solution, 2/ When you have found one but you still have some issues with it, then you share the problems with us. See [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create two graph view in xml.

```xml
    <record id="country_graph_id" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">country.graph</field>
        <field name="model">your.model</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <graph string="By Country" type="bar">
                <field name="your fields"/>
                <field name="your_field2"/>
            </graph>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="country_gender_id" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">gender.graph</field>
        <field name="model">your.model</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <graph string="By Gender" type="bar">
                <field name="your_field3"/>
                <field name="your_field4"/>
            </graph>
        </field>
    </record>
```

after that, you need to create two actions and two menus like,

```xml
<record id="action_for_country_graph" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">By Country</field>
    <field name="res_model">your.model</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">graph</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="country_graph_id"/>
</record>

<record id="action_for_gender_graph" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">By gender</field>
    <field name="res_model">your.model</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">graph</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="gender_graph_id"/>
</record>


<menuitem action="action_for_country_graph" id="menu_country_graph_id"
    sequence="1" name='Country Graph' parent='parent.menu'/>

<menuitem action="action_for_gender_graph" id="menu_gender_graph_id"
    sequence="2" name='Gender Graph' parent='parent.menu'/>
```