# Odoo 8.0: How to link menu items to correct views? How to link form view to correct tree view?

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo, formview

Based on [Create two graph view for one model openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731167/create-two-graph-view-for-one-model-openerp) I've made 2 different tree views for one model in Odoo V8.0.
This works fine.

But now I also want to add form views for those 2 tree views.
When I add a form view in the .xml, everything becomes messed up. I've tried many different orders in de .xml but I can't really get it fixed.

When I just remove the form from the .xml, the form shows ALL fields of the model. I only want to display some of them.

**This is my views.xml:**

```
<openerp>
<data>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_instellingen_id">
    <field name="name">opc_taginstellingen_tree</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
            <field name="tagnaam"/>
            <field name="lezenschrijven"/>
            <field name="logging"/>
            <field name="unit"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_instellingen_id">
    <field name="name">opc_taginstellingen_form</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="OPC Taginstellingen">
            <group colspan="1" col="4">
                <field name="tagnaam"/>
                <field name="lezenschrijven"/>
                <field name="logging"/>
                <field name="unit"/>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>        
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_actuele_waarden_id">
    <field name="name">opc_actuelewaardentags_tree</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree delete="false">
            <field name="tagnaam" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="tagwaarde"/>
            <field name="tagkwaliteit" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="melding" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="schrijvennaaropc"/>
            <field name="unit" readonly="True"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_actuele_waarden_id">
    <field name="name">opc_actuelewaardentags_form</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="OPC Actuele waarden tags">
            <group colspan="1" col="4">
            <field name="tagnaam" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="tagwaarde"/>
            <field name="tagkwaliteit" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="melding" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="schrijvennaaropc"/>
            <field name="unit" readonly="True"/>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>        
</record>

<record id="action_taginstellingen" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">OPC Taginstellingen</field>
    <field name="res_model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="opc_instellingen_id"/>
</record>

<record id="action_tagwaarden" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">OPC Actuele waarden tags</field>
    <field name="res_model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="opc_actuele_waarden_id"/>
</record>

<menuitem id="Toplevel" name="OPC Instellingen"/>
<menuitem id="Submenu" parent="Toplevel" name="OPC Instellingen"/>
<menuitem action="action_taginstellingen" id="menu_taginstellingen_id" sequence="1" name="OPC Taginstellingen" parent="Submenu"/>
<menuitem action="action_tagwaarden" id="menu_tagwaarden_id" sequence="2" name="OPC Actuele waarden" parent="Submenu"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

**The problems with this .xml are:**

When I click "OPC Taginstellingen" in the menu it shows the form "opc_taginstellingen_form" instead of the tree "opc_taginstellingen_tree".

When I click "OPC Actuele waarden" in the menu it shows the form "opc_actuelewaardentags_form" instead of the tree "opc_actuelewaardentags_tree".

When I change the view from form to list in the front-end, it just shows the title "Created by". So it doesn't go to "opc_taginstellingen_tree" "opc_actuelewaardentags_tree" at all.

**How it should be:**

When clicking "OPC Taginstellingen" in the menu: Show tree "opc_taginstellingen_tree". When clicking the button create ==> go to "opc_taginstellingen_form".

When clicking "OPC Actuele waarden" in the menu: Show tree "opc_actuelewaardentags_tree". When clicking the button create ==> go to "opc_actuelewaardentags_form".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**OPC Taginstellingen**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_instellingen_tree_id">
    <field name="name">opc_taginstellingen_tree</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
            <field name="tagnaam"/>
            <field name="lezenschrijven"/>
            <field name="logging"/>
            <field name="unit"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_instellingen_form_id">
    <field name="name">opc_taginstellingen_form</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="OPC Taginstellingen">
            <group colspan="1" col="4">
                <field name="tagnaam"/>
                <field name="lezenschrijven"/>
                <field name="logging"/>
                <field name="unit"/>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>        
</record>

<record id="action_taginstellingen" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">OPC Actuele waarden tags</field>
    <field name="res_model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>

<record id="action_taginstellingen_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="opc_instellingen_tree_id" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_taginstellingen" />
</record>

<record id="action_taginstellingen_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="opc_instellingen_form_id" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_taginstellingen" />
</record>

<menuitem action="action_taginstellingen" id="menu_taginstellingen_id" sequence="1" name="OPC Taginstellingen" parent="Submenu"/>
```

**OPC Actuele waarden**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_tagwaarden_tree_id">
    <field name="name">opc_actuelewaardentags_tree</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree delete="false">
            <field name="tagnaam" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="tagwaarde"/>
            <field name="tagkwaliteit" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="melding" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="schrijvennaaropc"/>
            <field name="unit" readonly="True"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="opc_tagwaarden_form_id">
    <field name="name">opc_actuelewaardentags_form</field>
    <field name="model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="OPC Actuele waarden tags">
            <group colspan="1" col="4">
            <field name="tagnaam" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="tagwaarde"/>
            <field name="tagkwaliteit" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="melding" readonly="True"/>
            <field name="schrijvennaaropc"/>
            <field name="unit" readonly="True"/>
            </group>
        </form>
    </field>        
</record>

<record id="action_tagwaarden" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">OPC Actuele waarden tags</field>
    <field name="res_model">opc_tags</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>

<record id="action_tagwaarden_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="opc_tagwaarden_tree_id" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_tagwaarden" />
</record>

<record id="action_tagwaarden_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="opc_tagwaarden_form_id" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_tagwaarden" />
</record>

<menuitem action="action_tagwaarden" id="menu_tagwaarden_id" sequence="2" name="OPC Actuele waarden" parent="Submenu"/>
```

Comment: I'm glad I've helped you @RobbeM

Comment: @forvas do you know where is the documentation in the odoo docs regarding this? I can only find this https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/actions.html .

Comment: @ricardgf I did not find anything about this in Odoo documentation. As a lot of things in Odoo, I had to learn it reading code from other modules. You can look for `ir.actions.act_window.view` with the command `grep -nrsH "ir.actions.act_window.view" /directory/where/odoo/is/* --include="*.xml"` (if you are using Linux), and you will find several examples. For instance, `res.partner` views use this notation (*base/res/res_partner_view.xml*).

Comment: Thank you @forvas, it was just to be sure i hadn't missed something!! With ODOO the learn by "searching how they've done it" it's the best approach as you've said !!

Comment: You, sir, are a lifesaver!